# Bootstrap-table refresh jQuery when using a search filter?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, refresh

I'm using an implementation of [bootstap-table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#table-events) with pagination, search, and clickable rows. The table works as intended when a search filter isnt used, i.e., it goes to the correct link when the row is clicked. However, right when the search filter is used the table's logic thinks the first row is still the first item, which is not true because it's based off user input.

Is there a way I can refresh the jQuery on a key press event in the input field, keep in mind the input field for the search is in the bootstrap-table.js file?

html/django code

```
<link href={% static "css/bootstrap-table.css" %} rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/bootstrap-table.js"%}></script>

<h1>Book Exchange Library</h1>

<table class="table table-condensed" id="table" data-url={% static "json/data.json" %} data-height="619" data-pagination="true" data-search="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="title">Title</th>
            <th data-field="author">Author</th>
            <th data-field="price">Price</th>
            <th id="id_col" data-field="pk">ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<!-- need this script to refresh on keypress -->
<script>
$(function() {
$("#table").bootstrapTable({
    onClickRow: function(row) {
      window.location.href = "/books/get/" + row.pk;
    }
});
});
</script>
```

bootstrap-table.js snippet (Might be helpful)

```
if (this.options.search) {
            html = [];
            html.push(
                '<div class="pull-right search">',
                    sprintf('<input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="%s">',
                        this.options.formatSearch()),
                '</div>');

            this.$toolbar.append(html.join(''));
            $search = this.$toolbar.find('.search input');
            $search.off('keyup').on('keyup', $.proxy(this.onSearch, this));
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [jQuery's .keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) function. With that you could do something like this:

```
$("#table").keypress(function() {
    $("#table").bootstrapTable({
        onClickRow: function(row) {
            window.location.href = "/books/get/" + row.pk;
        }
    });
}
```

It may not be a perfect solution for your problem; you may have to change the element that .keypress is called on. But something like that will run whatever code you put in the function body whenever there is a keypress event, which is what you're looking for.